# MS SQL - создать триггер для оператора insert

Tags: sql-server

Создайте триггер для оператора insert данного представления. Провертьте для добавляемой в представление строки нет ли совпадений по ключевому полю в родительской таблице. И используя значения полей добавляемой строки вставьте эти значения по отдельности в родительскую и в дочернюю таблицы.
Отобразите оператором print значения вставленных строк.

Я создал view из двух таблиц

```
CREATE VIEW ProductsUsers AS
  SELECT
    Products.Id AS ProductsID,
    Products.Manufacturer AS Manufacturer,
    Products.ProductName AS ProductName,
    Users.*
  FROM Products RIGHT OUTER JOIN Users ON Products.Id = Users.ProductId
```

Далее добавил триггер

```
CREATE TRIGGER Products_INSERT ON ProductsUsers INSTEAD Of INSERT AS
  INSERT INTO Products(ProductName, Manufacturer)
    SELECT Manufacturer, ProductName FROM INSERTED
  INSERT INTO Users(Id, Fio, ProductId)
    SELECT Id, Fio, ProductId FROM INSERTED
```

но при добавлении, выдается ошибка что нельзя именять сразу две таблицы.

Comment: И что уже сделано, что не получилось, в чем проблема? Дополните вопрос схемой таблиц, собственным текстом триггера, описанием ошибки или расхождения в ожидаемом и полученном результате, если такое имеет место.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Eduard123 добавьте ваши пояснения в вопрос. Кнопка правка. А комментарии уберите.